# MariaDB Replication stopped over New Year 2021/2022 - all seems fine, but no data flows

Tags: mariadb, replication

I am replication from one MariaDb 10.6 on windows to a MariaDB on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Server version: 10.5.13-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server)
It has been working fine for a few weeks, but it has stopped working and the last data was received on new years eve.

On the Master I have the following logs:

```
MariaDB [stdws]> SHOW BINARY LOGS;
+----------+-----------+
| Log_name | File_size |
+----------+-----------+
| .000098  | 104857723 |
| .000099  | 104857700 |
| .000100  | 104857730 |
| .000101  | 104858096 |
| .000102  | 104857886 |
| .000103  | 104857729 |
| .000104  | 104858105 |
| .000105  | 104857803 |
| .000106  | 104857785 |
| .000107  | 104857906 |
| .000108  | 104857886 |
| .000109  | 104857790 |
| .000110  | 104857826 |
| .000111  | 104858473 |
| .000112  | 104857653 |
| .000113  |   9040227 |
+----------+-----------+
```

And the Master Status

```
MariaDB [stdws]> SHOW MASTER STATUS;
+---------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File    | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+---------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| .000113 |  9445790 | stdws        |                  |
+---------+----------+--------------+------------------+
```

On the client my status is as follows

```
MariaDB [stdws]> show replica status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                   Master_Host: 172.29.3.10
                   Master_User: repl_client
                   Master_Port: 3306
                 Connect_Retry: 10
               Master_Log_File: .000106
           Read_Master_Log_Pos: 84917475
                Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000001
                 Relay_Log_Pos: 4
         Relay_Master_Log_File: .000106
              Slave_IO_Running: Yes
             Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
               Replicate_Do_DB:
           Replicate_Ignore_DB:
            Replicate_Do_Table:
        Replicate_Ignore_Table:
       Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
   Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                    Last_Errno: 0
                    Last_Error:
                  Skip_Counter: 0
           Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 84917475
               Relay_Log_Space: 256
               Until_Condition: None
                Until_Log_File:
                 Until_Log_Pos: 0
            Master_SSL_Allowed: No
            Master_SSL_CA_File:
            Master_SSL_CA_Path:
               Master_SSL_Cert:
             Master_SSL_Cipher:
                Master_SSL_Key:
         Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
 Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                 Last_IO_Errno: 0
                 Last_IO_Error:
                Last_SQL_Errno: 0
                Last_SQL_Error:
   Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
              Master_Server_Id: 1
                Master_SSL_Crl:
            Master_SSL_Crlpath:
                    Using_Gtid: No
                   Gtid_IO_Pos:
       Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids:
   Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids:
                 Parallel_Mode: optimistic
                     SQL_Delay: 0
           SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
       Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
              Slave_DDL_Groups: 0
Slave_Non_Transactional_Groups: 0
    Slave_Transactional_Groups: 0
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

I can easily ping between the two machines, but I do not see data from 2022 in the replica.
There is 1 hour of time difference between the two machines. (Iceland vs Denmark).

```
2021-12-20 10:44:44 3962 [Warning] Aborted connection 3962 to db: 'stdws' user: 'root' host: 'grafana.docker_default' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
2021-12-28 17:59:49 68303 [Warning] Aborted connection 68303 to db: 'stdws' user: 'root' host: 'grafana.docker_default' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
2021-12-31 12:16:39 5 [Note] Slave I/O thread: Failed reading log event, reconnecting to retry, log '.000106' at position 84917475
2021-12-31 12:16:57 5 [ERROR] Slave I/O: error reconnecting to master 'repl_client@172.29.3.10:3306' - retry-time: 10  maximum-retries: 86400  message: Can't connect to server on '172.29.3.10' (113 "Host is unreachable"), Internal MariaDB error code: 2003
2021-12-31 12:23:40 5 [Note] Slave: connected to master 'repl_client@172.29.3.10:3306',replication resumed in log '.000106' at position 84917475
```

This was the last message in the logs.

Comment: One of your servers (the client OR the master) cannot find the other one.... did you check if both of them ar OK, and reachable (from each other)? If they can connect to each otherer, maybe try to restart the client ? (From the showed logging, this should have noting todo with 'New Year')

Comment: >I can easily ping between the two machines, but I do not see data from 2022 in the replica. There is 1 hour of time difference between the two machines. (Iceland vs Denmark).
So the network issue seems to have been short? And now the IP Connection is fine.

Comment: @AndreasM_DK
need to rebuild the salve.

Answer (score 0):

On the slave, run:

```
STOP SLAVE;
START SLAVE;
```

if that doesn't wake it up, reinitialize the connection point:

```
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='.000106', MASTER_LOG_POS=84917475;
START SLAVE;
```

If it still doesn't work, do a full reinitialization of the slave connection:

```
STOP SLAVE;
RESET SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='.000106',
    MASTER_LOG_POS=84917475,
    MASTER_USER='repl_client',
    MASTER_PASSWORD='your_password',
    MASTER_HOST='172.29.3.10';
START SLAVE;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordan Bobic! I tried this, but It did not help. 
It shows the same Replica status as before.

Comment: Is it choking on a specific transaction at that point? Is the CPU on the slave maxed out on one thread?

Comment: It was actually an MTU Level setting on our VPN Connection that was causing the network connection to be unstable.